# React production build - set up Router with homepage in package.json

Tags: reactjs, react-router, package.json

I am trying to make a production build of my create-react-app, but the build/index.html displays the unknown Route.

Here is my Router.js:

```
const Router = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`/`} exact render={() => <LandingPage />} />
                <Route path={`/details`} exact render={() => <Details />} />
                <Route exact render={() => <ErrorComponent msg='Nie znaleziono strony'/>} />
            </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Router;
```

And here is the beginning of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tvshows",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
...
```

What I get from index.html is the `<ErrorComponent />`. What am I doing wrong?

**Resolved** by deploying app at surge.sh

Answer (score 0):

### No path for Router

in this line you have not write path={...}

```
<Route exact render={() => <ErrorComponent msg='Nie znaleziono strony'/>} />
```

the `"homepage": ".",` in the package.json is define which address your app will be open in